# Achartengine getRange method issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, graph, achartengine

I am having issues with Achartengine's XYSeries getRange(double, double, int) method.

I am new to Java programming so this issue sort of boggles me.

I am not sure how to use it, since I always get errors when I try it! What is the object that goes in front of it to get values from getRange? I.E:

*object here*.getRange(double, double, int);

and would I set that equal to something too? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the object that goes in front of it to get values from
>   getRange?

```
  XYSeries.getRange(double start, double stop, int beforeAfterPoints);
```

Returns submap of x and y values according to the given start and end

> and would I set that equal to something too?

Use it like this :

```
SortedMap<Double, Double> map = XYSeries.getRange(double start, double stop, int beforeAfterPoints);
```

to get y for x value

```
map.get(X_Value);
```

Links:

[Class XYSeries](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/model/XYSeries.html)

[Viewing Sub Maps](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/ViewingSubMaps.htm)

Hope this helped you.